# Distributing a cross platform python3 script

Tags: python

I have a python project which I want to work cross-platform. 
The approach I am taking to make sure that all the dependencies are installed on the user's machine is that I have a setup script that tries to import all the dependencies for my project, and if it encounters an import error, It installs the dependencies globally. The problem with this approach is that one I am installing  packages globally, and two that I have to hand edit my psuedo setup script to add any new dependencies.This solution seems very clunky to me. Is there a better approach for solving this problem.

Comment: Why don't you write a proper `setup.py`, and/or provide a `requirements.txt` for `pip` to use? See e.g. http://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/ for getting a project set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to [go the normal way](https://docs.python.org/2/distributing/index.html), the simplest solution would be to create a [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) for the dependencies.

If you dont want to install stuff globally use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) or [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to create an isolated envrionment - both tools also install pip which is needed for installing via requirements.txt